# How do I sort a list of lists by their sum and inner elements?

Tags: sorting, haskell

How do I sort `[[2,3,1], [0,0], [1,0,4,3]]` so that I get  `[[0,0], [1,2,3], [0,1,3,4]]`?

I want to

1. sort each sub-list and then
2. sort total list by sum of their item

I have some Python experience, and there are builtin-functions like `sort(list, key=sum)`. However, I don't know how to do the same in Haskell. Could someone help me out of here?

Comment: Not sure if you want Python or Haskell

Comment: @Adirio I want it Haskell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sort sub-list: `map sort`. You get a list of sorted list
2. Sort it by sum of sub-lsit `sortOn sum`

`sortOn` is the counterpart of `sort(list, key=sum)` in Haskell:

`sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`

Sorting:

```
import Data.List

doubleSort :: (Ord a, Num a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
doubleSort = sortOn sum . map sort
```

or

```
doubleSort dlist = sortOn sum (map sort dlist)
```

Thanks, [Zeta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139697/zeta).

Comment: Or, if you want it point-free:  `sortBy (comparing sum) . map sort`.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks! That's more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort all inner lists then you can just apply `sort` function to each inner list, which is just `map sort` in *Haskell*.

If you then want to sort all lists by some comparator, you can use very understandable function `sortBy`. But `sortBy` function example from [wentao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3853711/wentao) answer is not efficient because it will calculate sum of each sublist every time. Instead it is better to use `sortOn` function which uses memoization of results. And it is even shorter. So correct solution is next:

```
import Data.List (sortOn)

sumSort :: (Ord a, Num a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
sumSort = sortOn sum . map sort
```

Comment: I think he just have his answer modified, a bit earlier than yours.

Comment: Keep in mind that `sortOn` is only available for GHC 7.10+ (base-4.8.0.0).

Comment: > 2016
> use GHC below 7.10